# lighttpd server error 413 'request too large'

Tags: lighttpd

How can I avoid error 413 'request too large' on **lighttpd server**?
Is there a relevant parameter in the configuration file that I change to increase the threshold?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a relevant parameter in the configuration file that I change to increase the threshold?

Have you tried reading the documentation?
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ConfigurationOptions

```
server.max-request-size           maximum size in kbytes of the request
server.max-request-field-size     maximum size of the request header (in bytes)
```